Japanese input not working in firefox Ubuntu 24.04.1
I often use japanese input but for some reason on 24.04.1 when I switch to Mozc Japanese input it's not working but just in firefox. If I type elsewhere in the os it seems to work fine. The only thing I can think of is maybe this is an issue with using snap packages? However I wanted to check before I went through the process of switching from Snap to deb.

Snap could be an issue. Can you switch from snap to deb and let us know if that works? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

okay so this did work reverting to deb and that is making it work. I am not sure if that means this is a bug in snap? Also firefox prompted me that I needed to add an apparmor profile. I did that but I am not 100% it's correct. I do see    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox (65559) firefox when checking app_armor_status so I assume it's right.

I believe it's different because it actually represents a bug in how snap works. Not accepting different keyboard layouts in the firefox snap was the issue. I wasn't looking to switch to a deb. I just had to switch to a deb to workaround an issue in snap.

I understand that it is a different question, but it works as a workaround for your problem. I added the link as a duplicate so that future users can find it (the system added the rest of the text as an automated response)

For some reason Mozc Japanese input does not work with firefox snap package it only works with the deb package version of firefox you can follow these instructions: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04
some things of note that I didn't expect is that:

snap remove could not delete the firefox directory because it wasn't empty I had to delete that manually.
I add to add an apparmor profile manually for firefox see this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux?as=u&utm_source=inproduct#w_security-features-warning

Once I did these things keyboard input for japanese using mozc worked without issue though it does raise the question if there is some issue with the snap package for firefox in general.
